# Android after ondestroy, still can see application

Tags: android, ondestroy

I press backbutton to finish activity. It calls `ondestroy`. And goes to home. But still, after that i can see in android studio, it is still active.

I look at

```
Android monitor
```

and `monitors` tab.

```
free 3
allocated 27 mb
```

My code for ondestroy and backbutton:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mainactivitymp3 backbuttpn");

        final Context ctx = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("end app?");
        //builder.setMessage("yes?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityondestry");
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mMediaPlayer!=null ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityondestry mediaisplay not null");
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityonondestry mediaisplayisplaying"+mMediaPlayer.isPlaying());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityonstop");
        super.onStop();

        if(mMediaPlayer!=null ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityonstop mediaisplay not null");
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
          //  mMediaPlayer.release();//i usethis ondestroy
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "mainactivityonstop mediaisplayisplaying"+mMediaPlayer.isPlaying());
        }
    }
```

I have samsung tablet. When i press left button near home, it shows apps that i used recent or which memory still keeps.  I dont know which is true.

At least 20 minutes past but still i can see my activity there.

Those are logs:(for 20 minutes, after i went to home, no log from my tag, but for verbose, it keeps going on)

```
mainactivitymp3 backbuttpn
mainactivityonpause***********
mainactivityonpause mediaisplay not null isplaying
mainactivityonpause ends***********
mainactivityonstop
mainactivityonstop mediaisplay not null
mainactivityondestry
mainactivityondestry mediaisplay not null
```

When i choose my app from tablet button menu, it starts from oncreate. Possibly as if i run it first time.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your application is not killed. It will be still in Android OS memory.

What you might have to do is

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // This above line close correctly 
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly i have checked the Process ID after pressing back button. "Pid is " + android.os.Process.myPid(). A new process is created on every launch.